# PHP error shows MySQL server has gone away error

Tags: php, mysql

When I try to upload large audio (40 MB File) on the server and insert that values into the database then the file should successfully be uploaded on the server but data does not insert into the database it shows

> "MySQL server has gone away"

can anyone tell me the solution of this error.

Comment: You will always get a better response from the community if you show us your code, or at least some relevant code relating to your question

Comment: I also prefer more details but the problem is in your SQL query and database connection. so I still pointed out some points in my answer so that you can check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The most common reason for the MySQL server has gone away error is
>   that the server timed out and closed the connection. In this case, you
>   normally get one of the following error codes (which one you get is
>   operating system-dependent).

What error code you are getting?

> CR_SERVER_GONE_ERROR  The client couldn't send a question to the
>   server. CR_SERVER_LOST    The client didn't get an error when writing to
>   the server, but it didn't get a full answer (or any answer) to the
>   question.

By default, the server closes the connection after eight hours if nothing has happened. You can change the time limit by setting the wait_timeout variable when you start mysqld. See Section 5.1.8, “Server System Variables”.

If you have a script, you just have to issue the query again for the client to do an automatic reconnection. This assumes that you have automatic reconnection in the client enabled (which is the default for the mysql command-line client).

Some other common reasons for the MySQL server has gone away error are:

> You (or the db administrator) has killed the running thread with a
>   KILL statement or a mysqladmin kill command.
>
> You tried to run a query after closing the connection to the server.
>   This indicates a logic error in the application that should be
>   corrected.
>
> A client application running on a different host does not have the
>   necessary privileges to connect to the MySQL server from that host.
>
> You got a timeout from the TCP/IP connection on the client side. This
>   may happen if you have been using the commands: mysql_options(...,
>   MYSQL_OPT_READ_TIMEOUT,...) or mysql_options(...,
>   MYSQL_OPT_WRITE_TIMEOUT,...). In this case increasing the timeout may
>   help solve the problem.
>
> You have encountered a timeout on the server side and the automatic
>   reconnection in the client is disabled (the reconnect flag in the
>   MYSQL structure is equal to 0).
>
> You are using a Windows client and the server had dropped the
>   connection (probably because wait_timeout expired) before the command
>   was issued.
>
> The problem on Windows is that in some cases MySQL does not get an
>   error from the OS when writing to the TCP/IP connection to the server,
>   but instead gets the error when trying to read the answer from the
>   connection.
>
> The solution to this is to either do a mysql_ping() on the connection
>   if there has been a long time since the last query (this is what
>   Connector/ODBC does) or set wait_timeout on the mysqld server so high
>   that it in practice never times out.
>
> You can also get these errors if you send a query to the server that
>   is incorrect or too large. If mysqld receives a packet that is too
>   large or out of order, it assumes that something has gone wrong with
>   the client and closes the connection. If you need big queries (for
>   example, if you are working with big BLOB columns), you can increase
>   the query limit by setting the server's max_allowed_packet variable,
>   which has a default value of 64MB. You may also need to increase the
>   maximum packet size on the client end. More information on setting the
>   packet size is given in Section B.6.2.9, “Packet Too Large”.
>
> An INSERT or REPLACE statement that inserts a great many rows can also
>   cause these sorts of errors. Either one of these statements sends a
>   single request to the server irrespective of the number of rows to be
>   inserted; thus, you can often avoid the error by reducing the number
>   of rows sent per INSERT or REPLACE.
>
> It is also possible to see this error if host name lookups fail (for
>   example, if the DNS server on which your server or network relies goes
>   down). This is because MySQL is dependent on the host system for name
>   resolution, but has no way of knowing whether it is working—from
>   MySQL's point of view the problem is indistinguishable from any other
>   network timeout.
>
> You may also see the MySQL server has gone away error if MySQL is
>   started with the --skip-networking option.
>
> Another networking issue that can cause this error occurs if the MySQL
>   port (default 3306) is blocked by your firewall, thus preventing any
>   connections at all to the MySQL server.
>
> You can also encounter this error with applications that fork child
>   processes, all of which try to use the same connection to the MySQL
>   server. This can be avoided by using a separate connection for each
>   child process.
>
> You have encountered a bug where the server died while executing the
>   query.

You can check whether the MySQL server died and restarted by executing mysqladmin version and examining the server's uptime. If the client connection was broken because mysqld crashed and restarted, you should concentrate on finding the reason for the crash. Start by checking whether issuing the query again kills the server again. See Section B.6.3.3, “What to Do If MySQL Keeps Crashing”.